# Applying attributes to text in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am applying attributes to my text like so:

```
 //Great the number string and the rect to put it in
    NSString *numberOne = @"1";
    CGRect numberRect = CGRectMake(47, 100, 50, 50);
    //Create the attributes
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Academy Engraved LET" size:60];
    NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
    NSDictionary *numberOneAttributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [self darkGoldColor]};
    [numberOne drawInRect:numberRect withAttributes:numberOneAttributes];
```

I don't understand the array initialisation. Why do we use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle`, shouldn't the first item be a key? Where are the keys in this dictionary? Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialise any array here. `numberOneAttributes` is a dictionary. If you format it a little bit can be more readable :

```
NSDictionary *numberOneAttributes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
    NSFontAttributeName: font, 
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [self darkGoldColor]
};
```

These are key-value pairs. `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` is in fact a key - if you CMD+click on it, XCode will take you to its definition which is :

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSParagraphStyleAttributeName NS_AVAILABLE(10_0, 6_0); // NSParagraphStyle, default defaultParagraphStyle
```

By using system defined keys for attributes, the system can actually understand and apply them to your string.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Understand now